# What is the time complexity of A* search

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, path-finding, a-star, asymptotic-complexity

I'm new to stack overflow, but I'm here because I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find much info on the time complexity of A*, besides off the wiki. I would also like to compare it to Dijkstra's algorithm and see how adding a heuristic in A* improves it's performance.

I know it's a very advanced topic, but I just can't fully understand it from the info given on wiki (Even the analysis of Dijkstra's algorithm on wiki seems quite advanced).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could explain the time complexity in more detail, or suggest any reading / learning material on the topic. I do have a good understanding of the A* algorithm, but I've just started learning the analysis thereof now.

Comment: you might ask here instead: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Being E the number of edges and V the number of vertices, Dijkstra complexity is `O(E + V log V)`  ( `O(V^2)` for the naive implementation), while A* is `O(E)` ... what's not clear from the wiki ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simply **it depends**. **A star** by itself is no complete algorithm. **A star** is *Dijkstra with a heuristic* that fulfills some properties (like *triangle inequality*). You can select different heuristic functions that lead to different time complexities. The simplest heuristic is **straight line distance**. However there is also more advanced stuff like **landmarks heuristic** for example.

In the worst case you always need to explore the whole neighborhood so you won't get better than **Dijkstra** from a general point of analysis.
However in most practical applications you can achieve much better bounds.
This is only when you know some properties of your graph and of your heuristic function. You then can make some assumptions which lead to a better complexity, but only for those instances.

For example if you know that the **straight line distance** is always the correct distance in your graph and you use a **straight line distance heuristic**, then your **A star** will have the best possible complexity with `Theta(1)`. However this is a much to strong assumption for most applications. But you can think of where this goes.

The bottom line is: It **extremely depends** on the structure of your graph and your heuristic function.

Here's a lecture on **A star** as you ask for learning material: [Efficient Route Planning (A*, Landmarks, Set Dijkstra) - University of Freiburg](http://ad-teaching.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/route-planning-ss2012/get-video.php?file=lecture-3)

There is also much on the internet, the algorithm is pretty popular as it is very easy to implement and for most cases already fast enough (non-complex games for example).